# 2D particles with mass collision problem (JAVA)

Tags: java, collision

#### Preliminary

Hello,I am trying to model 2D particle collision for particles with mass. The physical formula is
[image]

The particles in my code sometimes collide properly, but most of the time just stick together and start accelerating uncontrollably (see Runnable gifs below).

#### The code and issue

I have an ArrayList of type particles, which have parameters `x` `y` `VelX` `VelY`, `mass` (which takes a double random value from 0.5 to 1.5) and some other unimportant ones. The `collide` method inside the Particle class is

```
public boolean collide(Particle other){
    return Math.abs(this.x-other.x) < width 
            && Math.abs(this.y-other.y) < height;
}
```

Inside the main program I run the function

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    for(Particle particle : particleList) {

        ArrayList<Particle> particleList2 = (ArrayList<Particle>) particleList.clone();
        particleList2.remove(particleList.indexOf(particle));

        for(Particle particle2 : particleList2) {
            if(particle.collide(particle2)) {
                
                particle.setVelY(velCollision(particle, particle2, 'y')[0]);
                particle2.setVelY(velCollision(particle, particle2, 'y')[1]);
                particle.setVelX(velCollision(particle, particle2, 'x')[0]);
                particle2.setVelX(velCollision(particle, particle2, 'x')[1]);
                
            }
        }
        particle.setX(particle.getX() + particle.getVelX());
        particle.setY(particle.getY() + particle.getVelY());
    }

    repaint();
}
```

where the `velCollision` method is as follows

```
public double[] velCollision(Particle p1 , Particle p2 , char dir) {
    double v1i=0,v2i=0,v1f=0,v2f=0;
    double m1 = p1.getMass() , m2 = p2.getMass();
    if (dir == 'x') {
        v1i = p1.getVelX();
        v2i = p2.getVelX();
    } else {
        v1i = p1.getVelY();
        v2i = p2.getVelY();
    }
    v1f = ((m1-m2)/(m1+m2))*v1i + (2*m2/(m1+m2))*v2i;
    v2f = ((m2-m1)/(m1+m2))*vi2 + (2*m1/(m1+m2))*v1i;
    return new double[] {v1f, v2f};
}
```

and I draw everything using

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    for(Particle particle : particleList) {
        Shape circle = new Arc2D.Double(particle.getX(),particle.getY(),particle.getWidth(),
                particle.getHeight(),
                0 , 360, Arc2D.CHORD);
        g2d.fill(circle);
    }

}
```

Here are some runnables of my output

#### Runnables (GIF)

```html
<a href="https://gyazo.com/79f0247a29935aea1f083d4aa3fa1a91"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/79f0247a29935aea1f083d4aa3fa1a91.gif" alt="Image from Gyazo" width="300"/></a>
```

```html
   <a href="https://gyazo.com/5e88ccc6710cd6f508fd43c0b1bf8601"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/5e88ccc6710cd6f508fd43c0b1bf8601.gif" alt="Image from Gyazo" width="300"/></a>
```

I am really not sure what I am doing wrong and what is causing this problem. If I change my `velCollision` method such that the two particle's velocities just get symmetrically reversed (mass = 1  for both particles), then the program runs fine and the particles collide correctly. Only when I introduce this mass difference factor that my output is erroneous.

#### EDIT

`Particle` class :

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Particle{
private double x;
private double y;
private double width;
private double height;
private double mass;
private double velX;
private double velY;
private float[] color;


public Particle(double x, double y, double width, double height, double velX, double velY,double mass, float[] color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y=y;
    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;
    this.velX=velX;
    this.velY = velY;
    this.mass=mass;
    this.color=color;
    
}
public double getMass() {
    return mass;
}
public void setMass(double mass) {
    this.mass=mass;
}
public float[] getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(float[] color) {
    this.color=color;
}
public double getVelX() {
    return velX;
}

public void setVelX(double velX) {
    this.velX = velX;
}
public double getVelY() {
    return velY;
}

public void setVelY(double velY) {
    this.velY = velY;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public double getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(double width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(double height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public boolean collide(Particle other){
    return Math.abs(this.x-other.x) < width 
            && Math.abs(this.y-other.y) < height;
}
```

}

Comment: All I may say is that the error starts at your collision detection. Please post your entire program.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think what I provided in the post contains all relevant information for this problem, other methods are unrelated ; the collision detection method is also already provided `double[] velCollision`

Comment: At least show use your _Particle_ class. PS when _m1_ and _m2_ are equal: `v1f = ((m1-m2)/(m1+m2))*v1 + (2*m2/(m1+m2))*v2; v2f = ((m2-m1)/(m1+m2))*v2 + (2*m1/(m1+m2))*v1;` becomes `v1f = v2; v2f = v1;`

Comment: PPS why is your _velCollision_ method not using your variables _v1i_ and _v2i_? This looks like a bug. And are _v1_ and _v2_ global variables or are they meant to be named _v1i_ and  _v2i_?

Comment: Thank you I corrected this typo. The particle class contains only the fields, constructor along with getters/setters, there is no anomalities on there. I also tried setting all the masses to be strictly different, still same bug :/

Comment: Just post the class _Particle_ please.

Comment: @paladin Allright the class is added. Thank you for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably found your logic error:

```
particle.setVelY(velCollision(particle, particle2, 'y')[0]);
particle2.setVelY(velCollision(particle, particle2, 'y')[1]);
particle.setVelX(velCollision(particle, particle2, 'x')[0]);
particle2.setVelX(velCollision(particle, particle2, 'x')[1]);
```

The first call of `particle.setVelY(velCollision(particle, particle2, 'y')[0]);` changes the fields of `particle`, when you call `particle2.setVelY(velCollision(particle, particle2, 'y')[1]);`, it uses different values than the first call (because the first call has altered the values). Just call your method only once and save the return value in a temp variable.

Like so:

```
tempArrayY = velCollision(particle, particle2, 'y'); // is this correct?
tempArrayX = velCollision(particle, particle2, 'x'); // are both independent?
particle.setVelY(tempArrayY[0]);
particle2.setVelY(tempArrayY[1]);
particle.setVelX(tempArrayX)[0]);
particle2.setVelX(tempArrayX)[1]);
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Btw, don't use setter and getter in such "cheap" class like _Particle_. It's a waste of time. Instead use public fields.